# while deploying my project using django i got this error

Tags: django

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x000001DA81D1C620>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Anil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in 
wrapper fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Anil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 123, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\Anil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 427,      in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "C:\Users\Anil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 18, in __init__self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\Anil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 49, in __init__self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Users\Anil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 207, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\Anil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 61, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "C:\Users\Anil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 44, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "C:\Users\Anil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 255, in cursor return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Users\Anil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 232, in _cursor self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\Anil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Anil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\Anil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 162, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
TypeError: argument 1 must be str, not WindowsPath
forrtl: error (200): program aborting due to control-C event
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source
libifcoremd.dll    00007FFBB0D094C4  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
KERNELBASE.dll     00007FFBF10E62A3  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
KERNEL32.DLL       00007FFBF3177C24  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
ntdll.dll          00007FFBF32CD4D1  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Anil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Anil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Anil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 301, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "C:\Users\Anil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 225, in close_all
    connection.close()
  File "C:\Users\Anil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 190, in close
    if not self.is_in_memory_db():
  File "C:\Users\Anil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 289, in is_in_memory_db
    return self.creation.is_in_memory_db(self.settings_dict['NAME'])
  File "C:\Users\Anil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\creation.py", line 13, in is_in_memory_db
    return database_name == ':memory:' or 'mode=memory' in database_name
TypeError: argument of type 'WindowsPath' is not iterable
```

Comment: Please make these errors readable or take screenshot from your errors. Thanks!

Comment: Upload your Code please. In this situation code helps to find which part of code is creating occur.